# OpenCV add black pixels from one Mat to another. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv

I'm trying to create an outlining image effect which takes an image (or video), finds the outlines and then draws them on top of the original image as a black line. I am currently getting the outline thusly:

```
Mat im = imread(...);
Mat outline;
cvtColor(im, outline, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
GaussianBlur(outline, outline, Size(15,15),2,2);
Canny(outline, outline, 0, 30, 3);
bitwise_not(outline, outline);
cvtColor(outline,outline, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
```

how would I then go about making sure that all of the pixels which are black get added to `im` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [setTo](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-setto) with a mask.

You should do:

```
im.setTo(Scalar(0,0,0), ~outline);
```

which means: in the image `im`, set all pixels which are black in `outline` to black (`Scalar(0,0,0)`)

---

Or you can avoid to use `bitwise_not`, and then avoid to negate again the mask. The final code will look like:

```
Mat im = imread(...);
Mat outline;
cvtColor(im, outline, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
GaussianBlur(outline, outline, Size(15,15),2,2);
Canny(outline, outline, 0, 30, 3);

im.setTo(Scalar(0,0,0), outline);

// or
// bitwise_not(outline, outline);
// im.setTo(Scalar(0,0,0), ~outline);

imshow("Result", im);
waitKey();
```

Comment: thank you so much, this was exactly what I was looking for. It looks great. :)